# Getting the index of boost::fusion::vector from a boost::mpl::vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

I started to play around with the boost fusion and mpl library and got stuck with a quite simple problem.

I declared the following types:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<char, int, long>   TypeVector;
typedef boost::fusion::vector<char, int, long> FusionVector_t;
```

Now I wanted to write a function that gets me the value from the FusionVector.

```
template<size_t N typename T>
T getValue(FusionVector_t fvec)
{
    return boost::fusion::at_c<N>(fvec);
}
```

The function works as expected but I would like to get the index from the boost::mpl vector and use it in this function and not pass it to the function as a template parameter.
But I did not figure out so far how to do this.

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find algorithm to get an "iterator" pointing to the first occurence of a type in an MPL sequence. Something like:

```
typedef boost::mpl::find<TypeVector, T>::type MplIter;
```

and then query the fusion vector at that "iterator"'s position:

```
return boost::fusion::at_c<MplIter::pos::value>(fvec);
```

However, I don't see why you use the MPL vector at all. IIUC, you'd like to define getValue as:

```
template<class T>
T getValue(FusionVector_t fvec)
{
  typedef boost::mpl::find<TypeVector, T>::type MplIter;
  return boost::fusion::at_c<MplIter::pos::value>(fvec);
}
```

which can work only if TypeVector and FusionVector_t "contain" the same sequence of types. In that case, why not only use FusionVector_t and write:

```
template<class T>
T getValue(FusionVector_t fvec)
{
  return *boost::fusion::find<T>(fvec);
}
```

Moreover, if you want to use "T" as an "index" into the Fusion sequence, this only makes sense if a given type appears only once in the sequence. A fusion::set would thus seem more appropriate than a vector. In that case, you'd have:

```
typedef boost::fusion::set<char, int, long> FusionSet_t;

template<class T>
T getValue(FusionSet_t fset)
{
  return boost::fusion::at_key<T>(fset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The MPL and the fusion vector are the same. But your approach seems to be much cleaner than mine. Also the reason for me to use fusion::vector was because I came from the tuple library. But I will stick to you proposal. Thanks a lot